# dynamic show/hide panels using Jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, slidetoggle

I've got a block of code that pulls all the list items from a SharePoint list via SOAP, then writes them to a page in the form of an FAQ. Because this list can get lengthy, I'd like to write them to the page so that only the questions are visible, and when you click a question, the specific panel for that question and only that panel becomes visible.

I've got the code working all except one little piece that's bugging the daylights out of me-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/someSite/System%20Resources/FAQ2.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/sites/someSite/System%20Resources/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".question").click(function(){
    $("#a"+$(this).attr("id")).slideToggle("slow");});

    var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>A Big Fat FAQ</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Question_x0020_Description' /> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Response'/> \
                           <fieldRef Name='ID'/>\
                       </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "/sites/someSite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
});

function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
    var iDesc=$(this).attr("ows_Question_x0020_Description");
    var iResp=$(this).attr("ows_Response");
            var iID=$(this).attr("ows_ID");

            var liHtml = "<div class='question' id='"+iID+"'>" + iDesc + "</div><div class='answer' id='a"+iID+"'><a href='/sites/someSite/Lists/FAQ/DispForm.aspx? ID='"+iID+"'>"+ iResp +"</a></div>";
            alert(liHtml);
            $("#FAQ").append(liHtml);

    });


}
</script>


<h1>A Big Fat FAQ</h1>
<div id="FAQ"></div>
```

Everything works EXCEPT that the click event of the question on the screen is NOT responding.

After putting in an alert to show me what it was outputting as the liHtml variable, I found out that it was inserting an extra set of  tags around the iDesc variable, so there was nothing to click.

```
<div class='question'id='5'>
<div>Why is the sky blue?</div>
</div>
```

I thought this might be the problem. The Question Description and Response columns were both set to Rich Text, which was causing the spare  tags. I changed them both to plain text, and it got rid of the surplus divs, and my question and answer divs both have the correct IDs, but it still isn't working. This is probably another one of those tiny syntax error things but I'm drawing a blank here as to what else could be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move code to toggle responses in "processResult"

```
function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
    var iDesc=$(this).attr("ows_Question_x0020_Description");
    var iResp=$(this).attr("ows_Response");
            var iID=$(this).attr("ows_ID");

            var liHtml = "<div class='question' id='"+iID+"'>" + iDesc + "</div><div class='answer' id='a"+iID+"'><a href='/sites/someSite/Lists/FAQ/DispForm.aspx? ID='"+iID+"'>"+ iResp +"</a></div>";
            alert(liHtml);
            $("#FAQ").append(liHtml);

    });

$(".question").click(function(){
    $("#a"+$(this).attr("id")).slideToggle("slow");}); 

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer.  You can't add the onClick listeners until the questions have been appended.

Comment: ok- that fixed it, with one very small caveat. Now I'm observing an odd behavior - when you toggle open, all is well. when you toggle closed, there's a minor "hiccup" on the closing toggle. It is distracting, but it doesn't make the functionality fail. Is this something to be expected, or is it something I can prevent with a tweak to my CSS file, or something entirely different?